# How do I output a list of inputs and outputs of a function?

Tags: python, typeerror

This is the current python code I am using to evaluate y = (exp^(-mu) * mu**N) / (n!) for 0 <= n <= N:

```
N = 10
mu = 2
n = np.arange(0, N+1)
numerator = (np.exp(-mu)) * mu**n
denominator = factorial(n)
function = numerator / denominator
print('N =', str(N), 'mu =', str(mu))
print('n = {:}'.format(n))
print('function = {:}'.format(function))
```

The current output I am getting is:

```
N = 10 mu = 2
n = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
function = [  1.35335283e-01   2.70670566e-01   2.70670566e-01   1.80447044e- 
01
9.02235222e-02   3.60894089e-02   1.20298030e-02   3.43708656e-03
8.59271640e-04   1.90949253e-04   3.81898506e-05]
```

What I want as the output is a list, not an array. For each value of n, I want the corresponding value of the function. I.e:

```
N = 10 mu = 2
n = 0, function = 1.35335283e-01
n = 1, function = 2.70670566e-01
...
n = 10, function = 3.81898506e-05
```

I have tried other methods, most of which have resulted in the following TypeError:

```
    print('n = {:.}'.format(n))

TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

I have managed to get this to work using a 'for' loop, but I would like a way to do this aside from a loop as I'm trying to do an exercise for college without using any loops.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: look at `zip` function, then try to format your print string

Comment: "I'm trying to do an exercise for college without using any loops" - I hate questions like this. You or your teacher are artificially restricting yourselves and it provides very little benefit to the learner. The `print` i/o will be much much more costly than a for loop.

Comment: `print('n = {:.}'.format(n))` -- what do you expect this to do? Why not just `'n = {}'.format(n)`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell sorry that was from a previous error message where I had left the {:.} in

Answer (score 1):

You can zip the outputs together, but you will need to populate n and function with a loop. Why strings?

```
n = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
function = [1.35335283e-01,2.70670566e-01,2.70670566e-01,
            1.80447044e-01,9.02235222e-02,3.60894089e-02,
            1.20298030e-02,3.43708656e-03,8.59271640e-04,
            1.90949253e-04,3.81898506e-05]

zipped = list(zip(n,function))

zipped

Out[ ]:
 [(0, 0.135335283),
 (1, 0.270670566),
 (2, 0.270670566),
 (3, 0.180447044),
 (4, 0.0902235222),
 (5, 0.0360894089),
 (6, 0.012029803),
 (7, 0.00343708656),
 (8, 0.00085927164),
 (9, 0.000190949253),
 (10, 3.81898506e-05)]
```

And I agree that not allowing you to print with a loop is a pointless requirement.

```
for a,b in zipped:
    print('n =',a,', function =',b)

Out[ ]:
n = 0 , function = 0.135335283
n = 1 , function = 0.270670566
n = 2 , function = 0.270670566
n = 3 , function = 0.180447044
n = 4 , function = 0.0902235222
n = 5 , function = 0.0360894089
n = 6 , function = 0.012029803
n = 7 , function = 0.00343708656
n = 8 , function = 0.00085927164
n = 9 , function = 0.000190949253
n = 10 , function = 3.81898506e-05
```

Comment: yeah I agree, the loop is much simpler. Tbh my whole degree (Theoretical Physics) is centered around achieving the same outcomes by different methods. I can see this is useful in labs where equipment is limited financially but I feel this is unnecessary in the scope of scientific programming.

Comment: @TS If you can figure out how to do that in better than O(n) time you will be rich.

Comment: @TS Also, how are you getting that code to run? I get `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` error when I run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.vectorize` in the following way

```
import numpy as np

def custom_print(n, f):
    print("n = {}, function = {}".format(n, f))

vprint = np.vectorize(custom_print)
n = np.array([1, 2, 3])
f = np.array([1, 4, 9])

vprint(n, f)
```

Output

```
n = 1, function = 1
n = 2, function = 4
n = 3, function = 9
```

#### Note:

As FHTMitchell stated in the comments

> The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

(from the docpage: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

Comment: I'd link to the docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html -- nb "the vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: Thank you for your commnet. I would add that to the answer. Perhaps the OP is interested in convinience.

Comment: Thank you yakobyd! Sorry I forgot to mention the college unit I'm taking is designed (albeit poorly) to maximise the use of python, essentially solving the same problems via different methods. I did know this method would be more convenient but my task this week specifically asked for this.

Comment: Let us know if they have a better than O(n) method for doing it. I'm very interested in that.